# What don't objects own __proto__ which is explicity set?

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I understand that `__proto__` is defined on `Object.prototype` so normal objects shouldn't own it.

But why don't object literals own `__proto__` even if it is explicitly set?

```
var obj = {
  __proto__: 'hello',
  normal_prop: 'world'
};

obj.hasOwnProperty('__proto__');   // false
obj.hasOwnProperty('normal_prop'); // true
```

Also strangely,

```
obj.__proto___ // {}
```

I thought this was due to `__proto__` being assigned a non-object, but:

```
var obj = {
  __proto__: {value: 42},
};

obj.__proto__; // { value: 42 }
obj.hasOwnProperty('__proto__');   // false

obj.__proto__ = {value: 'hello world'}
obj.__proto__;     // { value: 'hello world' }
obj.hasOwnProperty('__proto__');   // false
```

I see people referring to `__proto__` as a "pseudo property", and I guess this might be the reason, but I can't find details. I read the section on `__proto__` in the ES6 spec but it didn't help much.

This behavior is present in the current version of Firefox and Chrome.

Where should I be looking at?

Comment: A simple answer is "just don't use it". Try the MDN [*Object.prototype.__proto__*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) article.

Comment: @RobG Nevertheless, I am curious about the mechanism and why such behavior exists in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `obj.__proto__` is the equivalent of using `Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, ...)`.
The setter function is defined that way, according to the standard. So when you assign __proto__, you're in fact doing the same thing as when you call `Object.setPrototypeOf`. You're not really giving a value to a __proto__ property, you're assigning a prototype to your object.

You can see it easily like this:

```js
obj = {
 __proto__: {value: 42}
};

Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, {value: 43});

console.log(obj.__proto__); // { value: 43 }
```

If you want to go deeper, you can see details in v8 (Chrome javascript engine) source code, here:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/refs/heads/4.2.76/src/v8natives.js

You'll see that the setter for __proto__ is basically the same thing as Object.setPrototypeOf.

You can even mimic the behavior:

```js
obj = {
  __proto__: {
    value: 42
  }
};

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'fakeProto', {
  set: function(value) {
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, value)
  }
})

obj.fakeProto = {
  value: 43
};

console.log(obj.__proto__); // { value: 43 }
```

Obviously the last example is not exactly what happens with __proto__, it's just to show that some properties can have setter functions that don't simply assign a value. And the standard says that the setter for __proto__ needs to do the same thing as setPrototypeOf.

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful.